# PHP Issue with escaped hex characters

Tags: php

I'm running some PHP code and get an Error.

```
PHP Fatal Error:  Call to undefined function \\x66\\x6f\\x6f()
```

Below is the code:

```
function string2binary($string)
{
    $binary = '';
    $binarr = str_split( $string );

    for ( $i=0; $i < count( $binarr ); $i++ )
        $binary.=strlen(decbin(ord($binarr[$i])))<8?str_pad(decbin(ord($binarr[$i])),8,0,STR_PAD_LEFT):decbin(ord($binarr[$i]));

    return $binary;
}

function binary2string($binary)
{
    $string = '';
    $chars  = explode( ' ' , chunk_split( $binary , 8 , ' ' ) );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $chars ); $i++ )
        if ( ! empty( $chars[$i] ) )
            $string .= chr( bindec( $chars[$i] ) );

    return $string;
}

function foo( $bar = 'bar' )
{
    echo $bar . '<br />';
}

$fn = "foo";

echo $fn . '<br />';

$fn();

$fn = "\x66\x6f\x6f";

echo $fn . '<br />';

$fn();

$fn = string2binary( "foo" );

echo $fn . '<br />';

$fn = binary2string( $fn );

echo $fn . '<br />';

$fn();

$fn = string2binary( '\x66\x6f\x6f' );

echo $fn . '<br />';

$fn = binary2string( $fn );

echo $fn . '<br />';

$fn();
```

Output

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
011001100110111101101111
foo
bar
010111000111100000110110001101100101110001111000001101100110011001011100011110000011011001100110
\x66\x6f\x6f
PHP Fatal Error:  Call to undefined function \\x66\\x6f\\x6f()
```

I somehow need to treat the string as hex sequences instead of a flat string.  What does this error mean?

Comment: Can you give a textual representation of what you are trying to achieve? It's a bit hard to distill from the code. The error arises on the last line. You called `$fn();`. This means: Call a function that has the name that matches the value of $fn. Since $fn contains `'\x66\x6f\x6f'`, this is not a valid function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [stripcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php)

```
$fn = binary2string( $fn );
echo stripcslashes($fn) . '<br />';
```

Use that value to call the function, like this:

```
function foo() { echo 'call'; }

$bar = '\x66\x6f\x6f';
$fooName = stripcslashes($bar);

echo $fooName . "\n";
$fooName();
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/CjBBm